# Collectors.groupingBy on a Map Result to Nested Map

Tags: lambda, java-8, grouping

I have following code

```
 Map<Long,String> timeMap= new HashMap<>();
    Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entry<Long,String>>> output= timeMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
            .filter(map -> map.getKey()-Instant.now().toEpochMilli()>120000)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getKey()<600000));
```

I want my output to be a map nested map

```
 Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entry<Long,String>>> output --> Map<Boolean, Map<Long,String>> output
```

Could someone help me to write a `BiFunction` to achieve this.

Currently I'm using following approach to generate the output.

```
 Map<Long, String> trueMap = output.get(true).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    Map<Long, String> falseMap = output.get(false).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    Map<Boolean,Map<Long,String>>  booleanMapMap = new HashMap<>();
    booleanMapMap.put(true,trueMap);
    booleanMapMap.put(false,falseMap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nested `Collector` would be a better approach:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Long, String>> collect = timeMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey() - Instant.now().toEpochMilli() > 120_000)
    .collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.getKey() < 600_000, 
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
        ));
```

Comment: echoing that, I was about to start an answer when this one popped up. partitioningBy is the key here, not only because it works, but semantically as well, given the problem at hands.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way without streams:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Long, String>> booleanMapMap = new HashMap<>();
timeMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (k - Instant.now().toEpochMilli() > 120_000)
        booleanMapMap.computeIfAbsent(k < 600_000, dummy -> new HashMap<>()).put(k, v);
});
```

In order to avoid NPE, you should retrieve from the outer map as follows:

```
Map<Long, String> trueMap = booleanMapMap.getOrDefault(true, new HashMap<>());
```

If you want to keep entries in insertion order, just change `dummy -> new HashMap<>()` by `dummy -> new LinkedHashMap<>()`.